# How to verify android requests in server side using Google apis

Tags: android, security, google-api-client, google-api-java-client

I'm working on payment library and I want to make sure all of the receiving requests in back-end is from my library.
how can i do this by Google apps?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your API with the back-end server with client ID. Please follow this link:
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/calling-from-android

Comment: Thanks, but that link didn't help, I need a clear document, Google's documents are a little confusing...

Comment: hey folk , please clear which type of request you want to verify from the back-end server ? please clear me about it .